# I don't understand how to get over Stripe's rate limit

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to develop the backend of an ecommerce website using Stripe and NodeJS (Express precisely).

When the server starts, I am trying to fetch my products from Stripe. But after the first `stripe.products.list` call I get an error which says that I exceeded the api rate limit. This is not true because as it says in the [Stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits) the rate is limited to 25/sec in test mode whereas I am waiting 10 SECONDS before making my second call.

Please find below the function I use to make my calls. I simply use it in a loop with a sleep() function before each call.

```
async function fetchFromLastObj(last_obj){

    const data = stripe.products.list({ 
        active: true,
        limit: maxRetrieve,
        starting_after: last_obj,
    })
    .then((resp) => {
        console.log(`Retrieved ${resp.data.length} products.`);
        return resp.data;
    })
    .catch((e) => {  });

    return data;
}
```

The sleep function:

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const sleep = promisify(setTimeout)
```

The loop in question:

```
    var last_obj_seen = null;
    var nb_iters = 0;

    // fetching all products from stripe
    while (true) {
        console.log(`Iteration ${nb_iters+1}...`)

        let fetchedList = [];

        if (last_obj_seen == null) {
            fetchedList = await fetchFirstBatch();
        } else {
            fetchedList = await fetchFromLastObj(last_obj_seen);
        }

        fetchedList = Array.from(fetchedList);
        if (fetchedList.length == 0) { break; };
        last_obj_seen = fetchedList.slice(-1)[0];

        await sleep(10000);
        fetchPrices((fetchedList)) 
        .then((fetchedListWithPrices)=>{
            saveList(fetchedListWithPrices);//not asynchronous
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.error("While fetching products from Stripe..."); console.error(err); });

        nb_iters += 1;
        if(nb_iters > 100){ throw Error("Infinite loop error"); }
        if (nb_iters !== 0){
            console.log("Waiting before request...");
            await sleep(10000);
        }
    }
    console.log("Done.");
```

Comment: "loop" and "sleep" sounds suspicous.  How does your `sleep()` function look like and how do you use it ...

Comment: I used two kinds of sleeps, the first one was a dirty loop that increases a variable by one 100000000 times (something like that I don't remember the actual number) and the second one is a sleep in the form of a promise that I found on the web https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-sleep/

Comment: please update the qutestion with the code you are currently using ... Please add both, the `sleep` function and the loop you are using it in ...

Comment: so what does `fetchPrices` do? And I assume, that loop is inside an `async` block? BTW, you shouldn't mix promise chaining (ie `then().catch()` with `async/await`

Comment: Furthermore, your code will always throw, because the only way to exit it is, if  `nb_iters` hits `100`

Comment: I think that's it. I did not put everything for the code to be clear but now I think everything is here. fetchprice is basically the same function that fetchproducts but for the prices. So it does call the API. I just tried adding a timer before this call, thinking that could be the problem but finally it still fails at the second call of stripe.products.list

Comment: You still don't show what `fetchPrices` does. From the naming and the parameters it gets, I assume it tries to receive the prices for all of your products? How many products are there in one batch? Does this method only do a single request or a request per product? Do you care for the api limit inside `fetchPrices` also?

Comment: fetchFirstBatch is the same than fetchFromLastObj, with the starting_after removed. Stripe's developers apparently did not think about making it work when starting_after is null or undefined so I had to define two functions with only one line difference...

Comment: You are right, for each object it calls the api, I am a bit tired so I just called one time sleep before the calls inside fetchprice. I just fixed it and I am trying now. But still, the multiple calls inside fetchPrice are working, it is in fetchFromLastObj that it fails

Comment: Well, how many calls are there inside `fetchPrices`? Maybe the following `fetchProduct` is the one to get over the limit ... Set `maxretirieve` for instance to `10`, so `fetchPrices` will stay below the limit for sure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than handling pagination logic yourself you can use [the auto-pagination feature of the official Stripe libraries](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto).

> Our libraries support auto-pagination. This feature easily handles fetching large lists of resources without having to manually paginate results and perform subsequent requests.

In Node 10+ you can do this, for example:

```
for await (const product of stripe.products.list()) {
  // Do something with product
}
```

The Stripe Node library will handle pagination under the hood for you.